# How do I create a scrollable dialog box (popup) of variable height as an overlay in css

Tags: css

I’ve seen a number of examples to try and solve this but I can’t seem to find one that works completely. I’m am trying to create a dialog box in the center of the screen as an overlay. Example 1 only as long as the dialog box fits within the viewer’s screen height. With position fixed in example 2 will not allow scrolling on increased height. If I change overlay position to absolute and dialog to relative it solves the height/scrolling issue except when I scroll down the portion that was out of view is not part of the overlay example 3.

example1 https://jsfiddle.net/jdjmmzd6/1/

example2 https://jsfiddle.net/jdjmmzd6/2/  (overlay height changed to 500)

example3 https://jsfiddle.net/jdjmmzd6/  (overlay absolute and dialog relative)

Example 1 shown below:

```
<html>

<style>

.overlay {
 position:fixed;
 z-index:9999;
 background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 text-align:center;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 top:0px;
 left:0px;
}

.popup {
 margin:0;
 position:absolute;
 top:50%;
 left:50%;
 -ms-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
 transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
 background:#fff;
 width:50%;
 height:200px;
}

</style>

<body>
 <div class="overlay">
  <div class="popup">Hello World</div>
 </div>
 page<br>filler<br>page<br>filler<br>page<br>filler<br>
 page<br>filler<br>page<br>filler<br>page<br>filler<br>
 page<br>filler<br>page<br>filler<br>page<br>filler<br>
 page<br>filler<br>page<br>filler<br>page<br>filler<br>
 page<br>filler<br>page<br>filler<br>page<br>filler<br>
 page<br>filler<br>page<br>filler<br>page<br>filler<br>
 page<br>filler<br>page<br>filler<br>page<br>filler<br>
 page<br>filler<br>page<br>filler<br>page<br>filler<br>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the dialog to have its own scrolling, you need to set a container for it. Then from there, you can set a specific height on the container with the ability to scroll (`overflow-y: scroll`) and then you set a larger height on the inner div. This lets you customize how much they can scroll in the inner div.

Note that because we added the container around the original dialog, we need to move your positioning logic to the `dialog-container`. Your example 1 was fine for positioning but what you really wanted to know was how you could make the dialog scrollable.

Here is the jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/augburto/085k68pa/

And inline code example

```css
.overlay {
 position:fixed;
 z-index:9999;
 background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 text-align:center;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 top:0px;
 left:0px;
}

.dialog {
 height:500px;
}

.dialog-container {
  posiiton: relative;
  width:50%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 200px;  
  margin:0;
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  -ms-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
  background:#fff;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <div class="overlay">
  <div class="dialog-container">
    <div class="dialog">Hello World</div>
  </div>
  </div>
 page<br>filler<br>page<br>filler<br>page<br>filler<br>
 page<br>filler<br>page<br>filler<br>page<br>filler<br>
 page<br>filler<br>page<br>filler<br>page<br>filler<br>
 page<br>filler<br>page<br>filler<br>page<br>filler<br>
 page<br>filler<br>page<br>filler<br>page<br>filler<br>
 page<br>filler<br>page<br>filler<br>page<br>filler<br>
 page<br>filler<br>page<br>filler<br>page<br>filler<br>
 page<br>filler<br>page<br>filler<br>page<br>filler<br>
</body>
```

Comment: Very nice. Thanks for the help! My only change is setting overflow-y to auto for the times when the dialog is in full view.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want the whole page to scroll with the modal. In that case instead of width and height 100%, use:

```
top:0px;
left:0px;
bottom: 0px;
right: 0px;
```

Be sure to add position relative to the the container element of the modal as well (in your case `body`).

```
body {
  position: relative;
}
```

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jdjmmzd6/3/)

Comment: Wow! I like this. I'm going to give this a try also.

Comment: One issue I see is that you need to scroll to locate the dialog box.